pubkey 33 or 65 byte
importmulti
   "success": false,
    "error": {
      "code": -5,
      "message": "Pubkey \"xxx\" must have a length of either 33 or 65 bytes"
    }

what its this

What do you want to ask exactly? Where is this code snippet from? People might not be in the same situation as you are and thus not understand what you are talking about.

I assume you are trying to use the importmulti remote procedure call (RPC). It looks like you provided something in the pubkeys key of the JSON array that did not adhere to the expected length of a public key.
